# Total number unique chromosome combinations in fertilized egg?

Tags: chromosome, gamete

Assume for this calculation no recombinations or crossover .

A male gamete (sperm) is haploid and has 23 chromosomes. These gametes can be selected from the father who has 2 pairs of 23 chromosomes each. So the total number of combinations for the male gamete is 2^23.

The female gamete (ie the egg) which is again haploid has the same number of total combinations 2^23;
These chromosomes are selected from the mother who has 2 pairs with 23 chromosomes per pair.

Thus the inital fertilized egg (ie one sperm plus one egg - ie diploid  ) I believe this means should have (2^23)^2 possible chromosome combinations. Is this correct ? This fertilized item would be diploid with 23 chromosomes in each pair; 23 chromosomes from the male gamete and 23 from the female gamete. Is my calculation for total combinations correct ?

Can one state that all these 46 chromosomes are always different? Ie for example the 2 chromosome #3 have a different DNA sequence ?

Comment: No. I suggest that you get a basic biology text book and look up chromosome pairing.

Comment: The fertilized egg is also called a zygote-ie the union of the male and female gametes.

Comment: Yes, and how does this apply to your question. You have some fundamental flaws in your logic!

Comment: @bob1 Seems reasonable to me, what am I missing?

Comment: There is no fundamental flaw; there are 2^46 possible chromosome combinations, excluding aneuploidy.

Comment: @BryanKrause The maths is right for combinations, but not about the last question, though there's some quibbling to be done there - is OP talking about the coding regions only? non-coding regions?

Comment: @bob1 I don't see much to quibble about regarding chromosomes being different; the chances of taking two Chromosome #3s from different people and finding them to be identical are sufficiently miniscule to ignore. Even from the same person it would be unlikely they're actually identical taken from two random cells.